# Get last purchase along with price

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the Catalog of a selected supplier along with the last purchase price which is the column `Costs` in the CommandDetails table as shown bellow :

`Product (idproduct, productName)`

`Command (idCommand, CommandCode, CommandDate, idSupplier)`

`CommandDetails(idCommandDetails, idProduct, Qty, idCommand, Costs)`

`Supplier (idSupplier, SupplierName, SupplierAddress)`

`SupplierCatalog (idSupplier, idProduct)`

I tried the `row_number() Over (Partition by ...)` and other methods but i'm missing something, my brain said enough.

Desired Result :

```
--------------------------------------------------
| SupplierName| ProductName | CommandDate | Costs|
--------------------------------------------------
|    SUP1     |   P1        |  01/01/2018 | 3,06 |
|    SUP1     |   P6        |  01/01/2018 | 1,65 |
|    SUP1     |   P8        |  03/01/2018 | 5,20 |
|    SUP1     |   P9        |  05/01/2018 | 8,00 |
|    SUP1     |   P10       |  01/01/2018 | NULL |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Null in Costs for P10 when the product has never been ordered.

My last attempt :

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(SELECT 
    Sct.idsupplier,
    SCt.idProduct,
    SCD.PurchasePriceCmd Costs,
    SCD.Qty,
    P.ProCode,
    P.ProName, 
    Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Sct.idProduct order by P.ProCode) rn
FROM SupplierCatalog SCt
    LEFT JOIN CommandDetails SCD
        ON SCD.idProduct = SCat.idProduct 
    LEFT JOIN Command a
        ON a.idCommand = SCD.idCommand
    LEFT OUTER JOIN StoreCommand b
        ON a.idCommand = b.idCommand
    INNER JOIN Product P
        ON P.idProduct = SCt.idProduct) t
where Sct.idSupplier = 4 and rn = 1
```

Comment: what's the result of your query?

Comment: it returns nothing because rn is always different than 1 when idsupplier = 4 for instance

Comment: I don't see `idStoreCmd` in your schema

Comment: I just edited it's idCommand, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
SELECT 
    s.supplierName,
    p.productName,
    latestCommandDetail.CommandDate,
    latestCommandDetail.Costs
FROM Supplier s
INNER JOIN SupplierCatalog sc ON sc.idSupplier = s.idSupplier
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.idProduct = sc.idProduct
OUTER APPLY
  (
        SELECT TOP 1
            c.CommandDate,
            cd.Costs
        FROM Command c
        INNER JOIN CommandDetails cd ON cd.idCommand = c.idCommand
        WHERE c.idSupplier = s.idSupplier AND cd.idProduct = p.idProduct
        ORDER BY c.CommandDate DESC
    ) latestCommandDetail
WHERE s.idSupplier = 4
ORDER BY 
    s.supplierName,
    p.productName
```

I don't have SQL Server going on this machine at the moment so you may need to tweak the syntax. The trick is just doing a link to a subquery that returns the top row sorted by the date descending.

I'm assuming the idSupplier for "SUP1" is 4 as per you example code above.

OUTER APPLY (the other optional join) will return nulls if no record is returned from the sub query. If you are only interested in products with prices use CROSS APPLY instead.

Also note that this query does not determine what to do if:
- there are two Commands for the same last date from the same supplier for the same product but with different Costs
- the same product is sold twice under the same Command but at different Costs

In both cases this can probably be handled by extending the sort order of the sub-query or by grouping/aggregating the sub-query.

Comment: Just Perfect ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
;with cte as (
select a.idCommand, b.idProduct, row_number() over (partition by b.idProduct 
order by a.CommandDate desc) as rn, a.CommandDate, b.Costs 
from Command a
inner join CommandDetails b on a.idCommand = b.idCommand
)
select
c.SupplierName, e.productName, cte.CommandDate, cte.Costs
from Supplier c
left join SupplierCatalog d on c.idSupplier = d.idSupplier
left join Product e on d.idProduct = e.idproduct
left join cte on e.idProduct = cte.idproduct and cte.rn = 1
where c.idSupplier = @SupplierNumber;
```

You can probably replace the common table expression at the top with a subquery, or take some fields out of the CTE and join them in later.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working but i had to add `Distinct` in the last select, cuz without it if for example if SUP1 (supplier 1) has 3 products in catalog i get the same result 3 times, if 4 then 4 times, is distinct really necessary or something is missing ?